# Which is better, autoincrement on database or through code?

Tags: database, auto-increment

Which is better, autoincrement on database or through code?
My instructor just told me that leaving the database as "stupid" as possible is better, and let the program do all the work. Isn't it the other way around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that to let the database "stupid as possible" is a wrong practice. The more you lock the database from having incoherent data, the more you can be serene.

Database provides you a lot of tools (like foreign keys) to ensure data integrity and consistency without using code. It protects you in case your code is not perfect. Better, if somebody write a new code using your database, he can know what were your intention when you created the database by looking at its structure.

So, to answer your question, for me, I think autoincrement is better. Database can manage this easily and it discharges you this task.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for to support my doubts. Thanks to the others also, have a good one!

Answer (score 1):

Problem with autoincrement in a database column is that the application doesn't know the value, thus requires an additional client-server communication to fetch it. This may slow down your application. Also it limits some types of inheritance mapping.  Having some other increment method (sequence) may improve that, but the drawback then is gaps in your table's IDs.
Please read [this](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/) excellent post for alternatives to basic autoincrement.

Comment: Database (generally) provides a "last inserted ID" function designed for this that is working well. But sequence is also a good alternative. All of this depends of context and used technologies.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the db should as "stupid" as possible, anyway autoinc is an exception as if you leave this task to the code you risk a lot of conflicts. 
Imagine two threads/processes that need to increment the same field: you must manually handle the conflicts.

workflow with 2 processes:

```
      1. p1 get the field value and put in a variable (var==FIELD==0)
      2. p2 get the same field                        (var==FIELD==0)
      3. p1 increment the value                       (var++)
      4. p1 store the value                           (FIELD==1)

      SCENARIO 1

      5.a p2 store the value as is (he "think" nothing changed) (FIELD=0) !!! ERROR reset value

      SCENARIO 2
      5.a p2 increment the value                       (var++)
      5.b p2 store the value                           (FIELD==1)        !!! ERROR lost 1 increment
```

Each "rule" and best practice has its exception, you need to analyze the context to get the right choice.